# Firebase Database Structured Query

Tags: json, firebase, zapier

I am running this structured query and it keeps erroring, I can't figure out what's wrong?

```
{

"orderBy": [{
        "field": {
            "fieldPath": "firstname"
        },
        "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }]
 "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "MarketingAcceptance"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "stringValue": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like it to orderby and then only pull the documents that have MarketingAcceptance "true"

Comment: Malformed JSON? It's missing a `,` after the `}]`.

Comment: thought it would be something small like that that my eyes have missed, unfortunately, it's still not allowing the Zap to run!

Comment: Have you configured the index for `MarketingAcceptance: ascending, firstname: descending` in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/indexes)?

Comment: I haven't, the orderby worked fine on it's own, I added the where clause, and it stopped working. Is that something that would need to be done?

Comment: I'm rusty on it, but if I remember correctly your query falls under the category of ["compound queries"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). To work efficiently, these types of queries need an index backing them. Normally a client SDK would throw an error along the lines of "This query requires an index. You can create it here: [preconfigured link to Firebase console]" which you then click to create the needed index. The REST API (used by Zapier) is barebones unlike the client SDKs, so it probably doesn't have this error handling built-in.